# Looking for saxon:evaluate() example code

Tags: xslt-2.0, saxon

I have a transform.xsl file with will process a input.xml. But there is also an additional config.xml file which will define additional clauses. For e.g. this is the content of the config.xml.

```
<Location >
  <DisplayName>
     <Attribute1>ABC</Attribute1>
     <Attribute2>XYZ</Attribute2>
     <action>concat($Attribute1,$Attribute2)</action>
  </DisplayName>
</Location >
```

So when transform.xsl will encounter the DisplayName variable within the input.xml, then it will form the value with the RESULT of the action expression defined in the config.xml file. transform.xml will call the config.xml just to get the result. (The action can be modified by the end user and hence these are placed outside the xsl file, within the config.xml).

We are using saxon xml processor version 9 and xslt 2.0. So we need to use saxon:evaluate(). I tried to find more examples of saxon:evaluate(), but couldn't find it more. Can anyone show me some examples of how to use it?

Thanks in advance.

***** This is an edited query to highlight the need of saxon:evaluate *****

Comment: I don't see any regular expression in the `regex` attribute, instead it seems an XPath expression, a call to the `concat` function with two variable or parameter references as the arguments to `concat`. It is not clear why you need that instead of just using normal parameters or variables for the stylesheet or in a separate stylesheet module, but in general if you need some dynamic evaluation or generation and execution of code a move to XSLT 3 can help where you have various options like shadow attributes, the `transform` function plus `xsl:evaluate` (if supported) to solve such problems.

Comment: Hi @MartinHonnen: thanks for your response. The use case is that when Location element is searched in the input.xml, it's DisplayName will come from the regex element of the config.xml file. 

I think we need to go for `xsl:evaluate`, that's the only way and Saxon supports this. But if I am using `<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:message>
   VALUE is = <xsl:value-of select="saxon:evaluate($regex)"/>
 </xsl:message>
  </xsl:template>`, I am getting the following error - **Static error in XPath expression supplied to saxon:evaluate: Undeclared variable in XPath expression: $Attribute1**

Comment: Which version of Saxon exactly do you use? You haved tagged your question as [tag:xslt-2.0], Saxon since 9.8 supports XSLT 3.0 and there we have the `xsl:evaluate` element. In earlier versions there is support for an extension function `saxon:evaluate`.

Comment: I can't see any circumstances in which you would choose to use an up-to-date version of Saxon and would prefer saxon:evaluate over xsl:evaluate. Although you say you're using XSLT 2.0, it must be better to use a feature standardized in XSLT 3.0 than to use a proprietary Saxon extension, when both are available in your chosen processor. And in any case, xsl;evaluate meets this requirement (by allowing variables with any name), while saxon:evaluate does not (the variables have to be named $p1, $p2, etc).

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example to use an XSLT 3 processor supporting `xsl:evaluate` (https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-30/#dynamic-xpath) (i.e. Saxon 9.8 or later with the commercial PE or EE editions or Altova 2017 or later) to process your "config" file:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:map="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions/map"
    xmlns:mf="http://example.com/mf"
    exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
    version="3.0">

    <xsl:param name="config-url" as="xs:string">test2018121301.xml</xsl:param>
    <xsl:param name="config-doc" select="doc($config-url)"/>

    <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>

    <xsl:key name="element" match="*" use="node-name()"/>

    <xsl:function name="mf:config-evaluation" as="item()*">
        <xsl:param name="config-doc" as="document-node()"/>
        <xsl:param name="element-name" as="xs:QName"/>
        <xsl:variable name="display" select="key('element', $element-name, $config-doc)/DisplayName"/>
        <xsl:evaluate xpath="$display/regex" with-params="map:merge($display!(* except regex)!map { QName('', local-name()) : string() })"/>
    </xsl:function>

    <xsl:template match="*[key('element', node-name(), $config-doc)]">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:value-of select="mf:config-evaluation($config-doc, node-name()), ."/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

So with a config.xml

```
<Location >
    <DisplayName>
        <Attribute1>ABC</Attribute1>
        <Attribute2>XYZ</Attribute2>
        <regex>concat($Attribute1,$Attribute2)</regex>
    </DisplayName>
</Location >
```

this would transform an input sample with e.g.

```
<Root>
    <Items>
        <Item>
            <Data>data 1</Data>
            <Location>location 1</Location>
        </Item>
        <Item>
            <Data>data 2</Data>
            <Location>location 2</Location>
        </Item>
    </Items>
</Root>
```

into

```
<Root>
    <Items>
        <Item>
            <Data>data 1</Data>
            <Location>ABCXYZ location 1</Location>
        </Item>
        <Item>
            <Data>data 2</Data>
            <Location>ABCXYZ location 2</Location>
        </Item>
    </Items>
</Root>
```

That gives you a great flexibility to allow XPath expressions in the configuration files but as pointed out in https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-30/#evaluate-effect, also is a security problem: "Stylesheet authors need to be aware of the security risks associated with the use of xsl:evaluate. The instruction should not be used to execute code from an untrusted source.".

As for using the `saxon:evaluate` function supported in older versions of Saxon not supporting the XSLT 3 `xsl:evaluate` instruction, a simple example is

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:saxon="http://saxon.sf.net/"
    exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
    version="2.0">

    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="example">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:value-of select="saxon:evaluate(@expression, @foo, @bar)"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>   

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

which transforms the input

```
<root>
    <example expression="concat($p1, $p2)" foo="This is " bar="an example."/>
    <example expression="replace(., $p1, $p2)" foo="\p{L}" bar="X">This is example 2.</example>
</root>
```

into the result

```
<root>
    <example>This is an example.</example>
    <example>XXXX XX XXXXXXX 2.</example>
</root>
```

Comment: Hi Martin, we are using XSLT 2.0 and I have mentioned `saxon:evaluate` in my comment above. Do you have any sample code for the same? I have searched a lot, but couldn't find anything.

Comment: http://saxonica.com/html/documentation9.7/functions/saxon/evaluate.html has the documentation, it seems the parameters to be used need to be named `p1`, `p2` and so on. I am sure if you edit your question and add the [tag:saxon] and provide precise information as to which Saxon version you use you will get help from Saxonica/Michael Kay directly as to how to use that extension function.

Comment: @NirmalyaSinha, I have added a simple example showing how one can use `saxon:evaluate` in general. In the context of your original problem I am not sure it is useful unless you can ensure your used XPath expressions use parameter references named `$p1, $p2, ...`.

Answer (score 0):

Try checking the `xsl-attribute` tag along with the `xsl-value-of` tag. If I get what you're asking for, you could probably read the config.xml using the transform.xsl (or a second xsl for an intermediate file) to set the text inside the regex tag to correspond to the value of an tag attribute within the xsl.

https://www.w3schools.com/xml/ref_xsl_el_attribute.asp

Also, check this tutorial for regex in XSLT 2, it may help:

https://www.xml.com/pub/a/2003/06/04/tr.html